# rails 3.x pageless callback method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

I am working on integrating jquery pageless plugin with a rails application.  The pageless plugin works seamlessly when i write out the javascript.  The issue lies in trying to have a javascript method issued upon complete. What i am trying to accomplish is having a helper method to generate it, but it renders the javascript with quotes around my callback method which then generates an error in the javascript

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object reloadMasonry has no method 'call'
```

here is the helper method code

```
def pageless(total_pages, url=nil, container=nil) opts = { 
    :totalPages => total_pages,
    :url        => url,
    :loaderMsg  => 'Loading more results',
    :loaderImage => image_path("load.gif"),
    :complete    => "reloadMasonry"
  }   

  container && opts[:container] ||= container

  javascript_tag("$('#masonry-container').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
end
```

This is the produced javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('#masonry-container').pageless({"totalPages":3,
 "url":"/articles",
 "loaderMsg":"Loading more results",
 "loaderImage":"/assets/load.gif",
 "complete":"reloadMasonry"});
//]]>
</script>
```

the javascript results in having quotes around the reloadMasonry callback function

```
reloadMasonry = function(){  
    $('#masonry-container').masonry('reload');
  }
```

if i copy the exact javascript produced, and simply remove the double quotes around the javascript callback method ( reloadMasonry ) in this case, everything works seamlessly.

does anyone have any suggestions.